# Procedural realistic hair (Hair cards)

Tags: particles, hair, procedural, shader-nodes, particle-nodes

### What I'm aiming for

This is for procedural hair cards.

Basically I have one texture atlas containing 12 different hair strand types. And I want for every hair mesh generated by the particle system to be assigned to one of the hair strands from the hair texture atlas. To do this a good way of going forth is by splitting every hair mesh into 12 groups and every group being mapped to one spot in the uv space/ texture atlas.

### Process

I split my hair meshes into 12 groups using vertex colors and range/clamp/... nodes, what I want is to be able to say this hair mesh instance gets the top left hair strand and the next hair mesh instance gets one of the other 12 hair strands randomly. Basically creating a shader node system that procedurally decides which hair mesh to give which cutout of the hair atlas texture.

### Modulo node might help

I've heard that modulo math node may be what I am looking for but after looking through videos and post about it I don't understand how I would properly make use of it.

### How I distinguish between every hair mesh generated by the particle system

To elaborate on how I distinguish between every hair mesh I want to assign a separate texture to. I have the particle system give me for every hair mesh a different vertex value ranging between black and white, thus allowing me to by using greater and less math nodes decide what color get which position ion the hair texture atlas(or in other words which hair strand). Example: Every hair with the color pitch black might have the top right hair stand from the texture atlas assigned.

---

I got this amazing idea from *Daniel Bystedt*. Link to the video [here](https://youtu.be/oqjKMd9CYI4?list=PLveghVPT3X7Yh8DqV-OySOLxzwQC_fQAu&t=775). However he sadly does not show off the node setup.